# "Error in mysql syntax" with no real idea of the issue

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysqli, syntax-error

My code is throwing the error `Error in mysql syntax` on my line of code that inserts into the database. When I echo the insert I get

```
INSERT INTO patches (
 name, 
 description, 
 type, 
 com1, 
 com2, 
 com1,  
 code, 
 db, 
 other, 
 tfsID, 
 release, 
 createdBy, 
 createdDtTm, 
 updatedBy, 
 updatedDtTm
) VALUES (
 'testPatch2',
 'longPatchDescription',
 'Code - Full Build',
 '0',
 '1',
 '1', 
 '0',
 '1',
 '1',
 '98765',
 '6.11.0',
 'mhopkins',
 '2013/06/26 08:58:19',
 'mhopkins', 
 '2013/06/26 08:58:19'
)
```

I believe my syntax is ok. But I am very confused why I can't get more data on the error. Thoughts?

Exact error

```
Errormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release, createdBy, createdDtTm, updatedBy, updatedDtTm) VALUES ('testPatch2','l' at line 1
```

Comment: Could you add the exact error? I'd suggest that you were likely using an SQL reserved word as a column name, and you could get around it by using backticks around each column.

Comment: MySQL generates a more detailed error message. Whatever tool you are using is paraphrasing. Run the query against MySQL directly.

Comment: Post the create table for the table so we can see the column types, but a quick guess I would say that all those numbers should be 1 instead of '1'

Comment: added the exact error. I ran the query in mysql workbench and got the same text

Comment: @mhopkins321 - `release` is indeed a reserved word, so wrap it in backticks. Though you should think about renaming the field if at all possible.

Comment: You also have two columns of com1 `com1, com2, com1,`

Answer (score 8):

RELEASE is a reserved word for mysql, can't be used as a column name or table name unquoted.

List of reserved words for MySQL here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Actually. It can be used as a column name, you just need to escape it. But it _shouldn't_ be used, if it all possible.

Comment: renamed the column to `codeRelease` and that fixed it! Thanks. My timer is 9 minutes for an answer acception